# Source of Sanskrit shloka - Yadetaddhṛdayaṃ Tava Tadastu Hṛdayaṃ Mama

Tags: identification-request, marriage, sanskrit, shloka

> यदेतद्धृदयं तव तदस्तु हृदयं मम ।
>   यदिदं हृदयं मम तदस्तु हृदयं तव ॥

Transliteration:

> yadetaddhṛdayaṃ tava tadastu hṛdayaṃ mama
>    yadidaṃ hṛdayaṃ mama tadastu hṛdayaṃ tava

Translation by Max Muller:

> That heart of thine shall be mine,
>   And this heart of mine shall be thine.

Understand, the above shloka is a mutual marriage pledge.

What is the source of the above Sanskrit shloka?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find it in the [Chandogya Brahmana which is linked to the Samaveda](https://ia800108.us.archive.org/13/items/ChandogyaBrahmana/Chandogya_brahmana.pdf). More precisely it is the 9th Mantra of the 3rd Sukta of the said Brahmana.

Go to page 7 of the PDF.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

And, BTW, this Mantra is widely used in Bengali marriages.

Comment: Do you know the original context of the mantra? Is there an English translation of the Chandogya Brahmana?

Comment: Not sure about the translation but you will get an idea about the context from [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmana). " For example, the first chapter of the Chandogya Brahmana, one of the oldest Brahmanas, includes eight suktas (hymns) for the ceremony of marriage and rituals at the birth of a child.[13][14] The first hymn is a recitation that accompanies offering a Yajna oblation to deity Agni (fire) on the occasion of a marriage, and the hymn prays for prosperity of the couple getting married.[14] The second hymn wishes for their long life, kind relatives, " @sv.